# Prevent users from deleting a file in TFS

Tags: tfs

Team,

I am having this requirement to prevent users belonging to a specified TFS group(defined in my TFS 2013) from deleting a file. I mean the option to delete a file should be grayed out for the users belonging to that group. But they should be able to add and edit the file.

May I know how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, but if you weigh in the fact that deletions are not permanent and can be easily undone in the TFS Version Control, by opposition to a simple file system, then you'll realize that you don't need to disable the Delete command.

If someone accidentally deletes such a file, you simply have to turn on the "View deleted files" option of the Source Control Explorer (usually the 2nd button of its toolbar), locate the said file, "Undelete" it and "Check In" the undeleted file.

Regards,

Dan